# Reading a subset of the columns of the pandas.Dataframe from a HDF5 file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I saved a pandas.DataFrame in a HDF5 file. The DataFrame consists of multiple columns and has a very large size. The size of each table in the HDF5 file is >2GB. For an analysis, it is desired that one loads only a subset of the columns of the tables into memory.

Using SQLite3 this is a trivial job. One can just query using "select column1, colum2, ... from table1". Is there a simple way of doing this in Python?

Note that pandas.read_hdf is not a good solution. This function loads the entire table into memory and then drop the columns which are not specified with 'columns= .. ' argument. So it is inevitable to have a very large memory usage at the beginning.

Also, for the application it is desired to read the data in the form of pandas.DataFrame. Data will be produced with different columns later. If the data are saved in a DataFrame, an user doesn't have to decode whenever new data are produced. If possible, the chance of making mistake becomes smaller.

How could I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a `pandas` only solution, but you could go through the `h5py` library directly.
Maybe this could work?

```
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def decode(array):
    return [x.decode() for x in array]

def partial_load(filename,key,col_subset):
    handle = h5py.File(filename,'r')
    columns = decode(handle.get("{}/axis0".format(key))[:])
    rows = decode(handle.get("{}/axis1".format(key))[:])

    col_subset_idx = np.isin(columns,col_subset)
    matrix = handle.get("{}/block0_values".format(key))[:,col_subset_idx]

    df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=col_subset, index=rows)
    return df

# Fake data
nrow,ncol = (100,5000)
rd_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,[nrow,ncol]),
                     index=["row{}".format(i) for i in range(nrow)],
                     columns=["col{}".format(i) for i in range(ncol)])
rd_df.to_hdf('test.h5','abc')

# Load subset
matrix_subset = partial_load('test.h5','abc',['col1','col5'])
```

Comment: I'm sorry that this code resulted in an error. The idea here might be to take several columns as numpy array and then manually convert the array to the DataFrame. But is there a way to just extract a table with headers and the intended data types?

Comment: Nownuri, this code works for me (creates `test.h5`, and extracts a pandas df w/ only 2 columns of data). I added `print (matrix_subset.size, matrix_subset.shape)` and get: `200 (100, 2)`. If you read the entire **abc** dataset to a df, you get: `500000 (100, 5000)` for size and shape. When you say "_extract a table with headers and the intended data types_" do you want a numpy record array?

Answer (score 0):

Nowruri, Nakor's solution extracts a slice from the dataframe (as `matrix`). He creates (and returns) a new dataframe with the slice. His solution can be modified to return a numpy recarry (using pandas column names as field names).

Here's my modification to **`def partial_load()`** to create and return a recarray using `h5py`. This is valid so long as `matrix` is a single data type. If it has multiple types, you will need modify to create the recarray dtype correctly.

```
def partial_load(filename,key,col_subset):
    handle = h5py.File(filename,'r')
    columns = decode(handle.get("{}/axis0".format(key))[:])
    rows = decode(handle.get("{}/axis1".format(key))[:])

    col_subset_idx = np.isin(columns,col_subset)
    matrix = handle.get("{}/block0_values".format(key))[:,col_subset_idx]

    dt_list = []
    for col_name in col_subset:
        dt_list.append((col_name, matrix.dtype),)
    matrix_recarr = np.recarray((matrix.shape[0],),dtype=np.dtype(dt_list))
    for col in range(len(col_subset)):
        matrix_recarr[col_subset[col]] = matrix[:,col]

    return matrix_recarr
```